# Copy data from 1 data-set to another on the basis of Unique ID by map function

Tags: python, pandas

I am matching two large data-sets and trying to perform update,remove and create operations on original data-set by comparing it with other data-set. How can I update 2 or 3 column out of 10 of original data-set and keep other column's value same as before?

I tried merge but no avail. Merge does not work for me.

**Original data:**

```
id | full_name   |   date
1  | John        |   02-23-2006
2  | Paul Elbert |   09-29-2001
3  | Donag       |   11-12-2013
4  | Tom Holland |   06-17-2016
```

**other data:**

```
id | full_name  |   date
1  | John       |   02-25-2018
2  | Paul       |   03-09-2001
3  | Donag      |   07-09-2017
4  | Tom        |   05-09-2016
```

After trying this I checked manually I didn't get expected results.

```
original[['id']].merge(other[['id','date']],on='id')
```

Can I solve this problem with map? When ID match then update all values in date column without changing any value in name column of original data set

Comment: Do you want to keep the information associated with the  latest date for each row? Or what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to update only date column when ID of orignal data match with ID of other data.

Comment: try `org['date']=org['id'].map(othr.set_index('id')['date']).fillna(org['id'])`

Comment: @anky_91 use `replace` and you would not need `fillna()`.

Comment: @anky_91 that is a bug when passing `dict()`. here we pass a series. And it seems that it and the linked issued are both closed.

Comment: @anky_91 I'm talking about general case actually. in this case, no `nan` so `fillna()` does nothing, adds no significant run time. In the general case, `fillna()` will add some run time and the combination `map().fillna()` is slower (tested).

Comment: Even in that answer `##### TEST 2 - Partial Map #####` shows `replace` is faster (by a lot). And my test is for `80%` values mapped.

Comment: @QuangHoang sorry, I havent really dig deep on this, may be I am wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['date']=df['id'].map(other_df.set_index('id ')['date'])
print(df)

  id    full_name              date
0    1   John             02-25-2018
1    2   Paul Elbert      03-09-2001
2    3   Donag            07-09-2017
3    4   Tom Holland      05-09-2016
```

**to check other conditons:**

```
cond=df.status.str.contains('new')  
df.loc['date',cond]=df.loc['id',cond].map(other_df.set_index('id ')['date'])
```

Comment: Thanks, It works but can I also apply some kinda filter on it for example if there is 4th column in original dataframe called status.... only map when original id = other id and original.status.str.contains("new")

Comment: You can using loc. Please see my answer, i update a new case: to check other conditions

Answer (score 0):

Pandas' `DataFrame.update` does this, if you properly set `id` as your index on both the `original` and `other`:

```
original.update(other[["date"]])
```